# Adding partial (Razor) views in ASP.NET Core 6 WITH models in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, razor

I (new to C#) am working on a tutorial for a ASP.NET Core 6 Web App (w/ MVC), and have reached a juncture where I'm trying to Add a new Razor View (called "_CustomerDetails") to my "Customer" model. The person leading the tutorial has indicated that I should select an "Empty" ("scaffolding"?) Template, which appears as an option for him in HIS drop-down, as seen here:

[image: scaffolding_templates]

...but it does not appear that way for me! I only have Create, Delete, Details, Edit, Empty (without model), and List, as you see here:

[image: add-razor-partial-view]

Anyone know if this is a new version of .NET thing? Or a VS 2022 thing? The tutorial is being covered in a pre-6.0/-2022 version. Maybe I can use an "Empty(without model)" template and then modify to get the same effect?

Comment: You should be able to create an empty (without model) - that is correct. Later when you want to hook up a model you can add a `@model MyModel` statement to the top of the page.

Comment: I will probably end up needing to do it that way, thanks! Any idea if this part of the 6.0/2022 updates?